# Arduino Wifi rev2 lost UDP packet mitigation

Tags: arduino, udp

Hi i got a simple arduino wifi program that waits for UDP commands sent by a python script. When the python script sends a command packet it expects an aknowledge packet (and in certain circumstances some returned data packets). So basically there are two kinds of commands. SET COMMANDS which only expects an aknowledge packets, and GET commands which expect an aknowledge packet + one or multiple data packets. Right now, when a command packet is lost from the python script's perspective, a timeout is raised and the python script tries again after a small delay. For now, this does not cause any problems with the GET commands because, at worse the arduino replies twice and i receive the data. But this can cause problems with the SET commands. I.e. the arduino could get the command to toggle an led twice (on off on). What could I do to remedy this problem. Should i add some framing to the udp packet command structure like packet counters? The receiving arduino needs to know if there was dome packets lost and tell the python script to restart what ever action it was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of UDP that packets may get lost or duplicated. You have, essentially, three options.

1. If you need reliable data transmission, use a protocol that provides it. Using UDP is a bad choice where you need all the features TCP provides anyway. So switch to TCP.
2. Re-architect the protocol so that you don't need reliable data transmission. For example, your "toggle LED" command could include a sequence number and if the toggle sequence matches the previous one, it's ignored. So you send "toggle LED, sequence 2" over and over until you get an acknowledgement, then in your next request, it's "toggle LED, sequence 3". Be careful, not only may data packets get lost, duplicated or interleaved, but responses may too. It's easy to mess this up.
3. Implement reliable data transmission. For example, each request may contain a sequence number and you repeat it until you get an acknowledge with the same sequence. Only then move onto the next sequence. Do this with multi-datagram replies too. This is painful, but that's why you are offered TCP -- so you don't have to re-invent it every time you need reliable data transmission.